# create an observer for invalidate block cache event

Tags: event-observer, cache

is there an event i can hook on to run `Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->cleanType('block_html');` every time the Blocks HTML cache is invalidated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Michael Tessel has written a module that automatically refreshes invalidated caches you should check it out:

https://github.com/MichaelThessel/magento-cache-refresh

Comment: thank you i don't want a cron job I want an observer that listens for the cache to get invalidated

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not aware of any events being dispatched on cache validation.